# MediaQuery.of throws an exception inside MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm newbie in Flutter.
I have very simple app

main.dart:

```
import 'package:dart_test/views/widgets/items/pack_items.dart';
import 'package:dart_test/views/widgets/items/pack_row.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("app build");
    var pdata =
        PackData(packId: 'npack1', name: 'Pack1', name_ru: 'пак 1', nImages: 5);
    //print("~w:$contW");
    return MaterialApp(
        home: PackBody(data: pdata, offset: 0).build(context));
  }
}
```

PackBody.dart:

```
class PackBody extends ListItem {
  final PackData data;
  final int offset;
  PackBody({required this.data, required this.offset});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ar = 896.0 / 768;
    //var contWidth=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 50,
      child: Text('khkljgkjhgkjhg'),
    );
  }
}
```

And it throws an exception:
[image]
I tried to wrap `PackBody` with `MediaQuery` - no luck
Shouldn't `MaterialApp` provide `MediaQuery` down to the hierarchy?

Upd: I missunderstood the core of the problem.
The right pattern should be:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return //your widget  
}
```

Comment: What is `ListItem` here? Can you include that

Comment: Even without knowing what ListItem is, you are passing the context of MyApp which is not under MaterialApp in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is the same as writing:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("app build");
    var pdata = PackData(packId: 'npack1', name: 'Pack1', name_ru: 'пак 1', nImages: 5);
    //print("~w:$contW");
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 50,
        child: Text('khkljgkjhgkjhg'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `MediaQuery` widget establishes a subtree in which media queries resolve to the given data. `MaterialApp` introduces a `MediaQuery` and keeps it up to date with the current screen metrics as they change. In order for `MediaQuery.of(context)` to work it needs to be in that subtree, and from the previous code sample I provided it clearly is not.
Update: Adding full example below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Text(
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah indeed. The problem was that `MyApp` extends `StatelessWidget,` while it should extend MaterialApp

Comment: @undefined you are going in a wrong way about this, you should not create a new widget class and forcefully call the build method with your parent widget context.

Comment: I got it, see `upd` section.

Comment: @undefined I still think you don't quite get it. You don't need to put the MaterialApp into the main function, however you do need to make the widget in which you use MediaQuery in the subtree in which MediaQuery.of(context) is available. Generally you would make a widget just for the purpose of MaterialApp because there are many things which you will eventually want to customize there. I highly recommend checking out a tutorial like https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab

Comment: @undefined I updated my answer with an example.